# Why does a query run using either a button or a Div return inconsistent results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Using JS/JQuery.

What I want the user to do is click on the name that is displayed on the page and replicate the same action as what happens if the user clicks the "find" button. Basically to return the associated results back to the page.

The example page is here,http://www.kudosoo.com/friendslist.html so for example the user clicks "dave" and the result is the same as if they'd entered "dave" into the text box and clicked "find"

When clicked why does  `<div id="container"></div>`not return the same results as clicking the "Find" button, they both use the same query "friendFeed"

Perhaps its an issue with the way the string is stored?

```
<!doctype html>

<!-- Runs Parse and FB code that uses Facebook authentication to login user to the site and redirects them to the main content area. This page is fired from the Facebook button being clicked on the site landing page-->


<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="fresh Gray Bootstrap 3.0 Responsive Theme " />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Template, Theme, web, html5, css3, Bootstrap,Bootstrap 3.0 Responsive Login" />
    <meta name="author" content="Adsays" />
    <title>Parse JavaScript Todo App</title>



    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.17.min.js"></script>





</head>

<body>


    <!-- Initialize the Parse object-->


    <script type="text/javascript">
        Parse.initialize("79tphN5KrDXdjJnAmehgBHgOjgE2dLGTvEPR9pEJ", "9lblofQNZlypAtveU4i4IzEpaOqtBgMcmuU1AE6Y");

         // capture name of user thats been clicked
         // return their activty feed of badges etc

        var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

        var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
        query.include('toUser');
         // query.include('fromUser');
         //query.include('pic');
        query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
        query.equalTo("status", "Request sent");

        query.find({
            success: function (results) {
                // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
                imageURLs = [];
                Username = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var object = results[i].get("toUser");
                    imageURLs.push(object.get("pic"));
                    Username.push(object.get("username"));
                }


                // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
                console.log(imageURLs);
                console.log(Username);
                for (var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++) {
                    $('#container').append("<img class='images' src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");
                    $('#container').append("<div class='username'>'" + Username[j] + "'</div>");
                }

            },
            error: function (error) {
                // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }

        });


        var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        var myBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");


         // Captures the input from the user and checks if the name already exists within the Db.
        function friendFeed(name) {
            var friendName = name || $('#friendsearch').val();
            console.log(friendName);

            var query = new Parse.Query(myBadges).matchesQuery("uploadedBy", new Parse.Query("_User").equalTo("username", friendName));
            query.find({
                success: function (rules) {

                    imageURLs = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                        var object = rules[i];
                        imageURLs.push(object.get("BadgeName"));
                        Username.push(object.get("uploadedBy"));
                    }

                    for (var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++) {
                        $('#FriendsStuff').append("<img class='images' src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");
                        $('#FriendsStuffName').append("<div class='username'>'" + Username[j] + "'</div>");
                         console.log("here");
                    }

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    //If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }

            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '.username, #find_button', function (event) {
                //debugger;
                event.preventDefault();
                friendName = $(this).is("button") ? null : $(this).text();
                friendFeed(friendName);
            });
        });


    </script>

<div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
<input type="text" id="friendsearch" placeholder="Find Friend" class="input-field" />
<button id="find_button" type="button" class="btn btn-login">Find</button>

<div id="container"></div>


<div id="FriendsStuff"></div>
<div id="FriendsStuffName"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need a an event on click of dave that is from class .username

Just add :

```
 $(document).on('click', '.username', function (event) {
                 //debugger;
                 event.preventDefault();
                 friendName = $(this).innerHTML; // get content of user
                 friendFeed(friendName);
             });
```

Personnaly, I prefer to store variable that will be used on different function in attribute of element that you define and retrieve **$(this).attr("YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME")** rather that getting innerHTML of a div

and store your string on : `<div class=".username" YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME="Dave">Dave</div>`